# SearchView en ActionBar - Búsqueda sin respuesta

Tags: android, searchview

Vengo desarrollando una app con una lista que es llenada por una `WEBSERVICE` todo bien, hasta que le implemento el `SearchView` en `ActionBar`, Intente implementarlo como dice en este tutorial:

> http://tutorialsbuzz.com/2015/11/android-filter-recyclerview-using-searchview-in-toolbar.html

Todo corre perfectamente bien sin ningún error.

Sin embargo no busca, ingreso los parámetros y no realiza la búsqueda mi adaptador se queda en blanco:

> **Espero cualquier apoyo**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Esto es la parte de mi busqueda :**

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_form, menu);

        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
        searchView.setQueryHint(getText(R.string.search));
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        //
        MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(item,
                new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
                        // Do something when expanded
                        return true; // Return true to expand action view
                    }
                    @Override
                    public boolean  onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item){
                        adapter.setFilter(plazas);
                        return true;

                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        try {

            ArrayList<Plaza> listaFiltrada =filter(plazas,newText);
            adapter.setFilter(listaFiltrada);
        }catch (Exception e){

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        return false;
    }

    private ArrayList<Plaza> filter(ArrayList<Plaza> plazas,String texto){
        ArrayList<Plaza> listaFiltrada=new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            texto=texto.toLowerCase();
            for (Plaza plaza: plazas){
                String plaza2=plaza.getCodigoPlaza().toLowerCase();
                if (plaza2.contains(texto)){
                    listaFiltrada.add(plaza);
                }
            }

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return listaFiltrada;
    }
```

**AL parecer en la declaracion de mi ArrayList seria el problema
No se como declararlo en todos tiene el mismo resultado**

```
 private ArrayList<Plaza> plazas = new ArrayList<Plaza> ();
    // private List<Plaza> items = new ArrayList<Plaza> ();

    //ArrayList<Plaza> plazas = new ArrayList<Plaza> ();
```

**Esto es todo el codigo :**

```
    /**
 * Fragmento principal que contiene la lista de las metas
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public class MainFragment extends Fragment implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {

    /*
    Etiqueta de depuracion
     */
    private static final String TAG = MainFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    /*
    Adaptador del recycler view
     */
    private MetaAdapter adapter;

    /*
    Instancia global del recycler view
     */
    private RecyclerView lista;

    /*
    instancia global del administrador
     */
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager lManager;

    /*
    Instancia global del FAB
     */

    private Gson gson = new Gson();

     /*
    Instancia global para el refresh
     */
    SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;

    ArrayList<Plaza> plazas = new ArrayList<Plaza>();
    // private List<Plaza> items = new ArrayList<Plaza> ();

    //ArrayList<Plaza> plazas = new ArrayList<Plaza> ();



    public MainFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Habilitar al fragmento para contribuir en la action bar
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);


        lista = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.reciclador);
        lista.setHasFixedSize(true);
        // Usar un administrador para LinearLayout
        lManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        lista.setLayoutManager(lManager);

        mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout_main);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setDistanceToTriggerSync(80);// in dips
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setSize(SwipeRefreshLayout.DEFAULT);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                cargarAdaptador();
                mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });

        // Cargar datos en el adaptador
        cargarAdaptador();

        return v;
    }



    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_form, menu);

        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
        searchView.setQueryHint(getText(R.string.search));
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        //
        MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(item,
                new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
                        // Do something when expanded
                        return true; // Return true to expand action view
                    }
                    @Override
                    public boolean  onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item){
                        adapter.setFilter(plazas);
                        return true;

                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        try {

            ArrayList<Plaza> listaFiltrada =filter(plazas,newText);
            adapter.setFilter(listaFiltrada);
        }catch (Exception e){

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        return false;
    }

    private ArrayList<Plaza> filter(ArrayList<Plaza> plazas,String texto){
        ArrayList<Plaza> listaFiltrada=new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            texto=texto.toLowerCase();
            for (Plaza plaza: plazas){
                String plaza2=plaza.getCodigoPlaza().toLowerCase();
                if (plaza2.contains(texto)){
                    listaFiltrada.add(plaza);
                }
            }

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return listaFiltrada;
    }





    /**
     * Carga el adaptador con las metas obtenidas
     * en la respuesta
     */
    public void cargarAdaptador() {
        // Petición GET
        VolleySingleton.
                getInstance(getActivity()).
                addToRequestQueue(
                        new JsonObjectRequest(
                                Request.Method.GET,
                                Constantes.GET,
                                null,
                                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                                        // Procesar la respuesta Json
                                        procesarRespuesta(response);
                                    }
                                },
                                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                        Log.d(TAG, "Error Volley: " + error.toString());
                                    }
                                }

                        )
                );
    }

    /**
     * Interpreta los resultados de la respuesta y así
     * realizar las operaciones correspondientes
     *
     * @param response Objeto Json con la respuesta
     */
    private void procesarRespuesta(JSONObject response) {
        try {
            // Obtener atributo "estado"
            String estado = response.getString("estado");

            switch (estado) {
                case "1": // EXITO
                    // Obtener array "metas" Json
                    JSONArray mensaje = response.getJSONArray("metas");
                    // Parsear con Gson
                    Plaza[] plazas = gson.fromJson(mensaje.toString(), Plaza[].class);
                    // Inicializar adaptador
                    adapter = new MetaAdapter(Arrays.asList(plazas), getActivity());
                    // Setear adaptador a la lista
                    lista.setAdapter(adapter);
                    break;
                case "2": // FALLIDO
                    String mensaje2 = response.getString("mensaje");
                    Toast.makeText(
                            getActivity(),
                            mensaje2,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }

    }

}
```

**ESTE ES EL CODGIO DE MI  MetaAdapter :**

```
/**
 * Adaptador del recycler view
 */
public class MetaAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MetaAdapter.MetaViewHolder>
        implements ItemClickListener {

    /**
     * Lista de objetos {@link Meta} que representan la fuente de datos
     * de inflado
     */
    private List<Plaza> items;

    /*
    Contexto donde actua el recycler view
     */
    private Context context;


    public MetaAdapter(List<Plaza> items, Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public MetaViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item_list, viewGroup, false);
        return new MetaViewHolder(v, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MetaViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        switch(items.get(i).getEstado())
        {
            case "0":
                viewHolder.estado.setText("OCUPADO");
                break;
            case "1":
                viewHolder.estado.setText("VACANTE");
                break;
            case "2":
                viewHolder.estado.setText("RESERVADO");
                break;
            default:
                viewHolder.estado.setText("ERROR");
        }
        viewHolder.nivel.setText(items.get(i).getNivel());
        //viewHolder.estado.setText(items.get(i).getEstado());
        viewHolder.colegio.setText(items.get(i).getIe());
        viewHolder.especialidad.setText(items.get(i).getEspecialidad());
        viewHolder.codigo.setText(items.get(i).getCodigoPlaza());
    }


    /**
     * Sobrescritura del método de la interfaz {@link ItemClickListener}
     *
     * @param view     item actual
     * @param position posición del item actual
     */
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
        DetailActivity.launch(
                (Activity) context, items.get(position).getPlazaID());
    }


    public static class MetaViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
            implements View.OnClickListener {
        // Campos respectivos de un item
        public TextView nivel;
        public TextView estado;
        public TextView colegio;
        public TextView especialidad;
        public TextView codigo;
        public ItemClickListener listener;


        public MetaViewHolder(View v, ItemClickListener listener) {
            super(v);
            nivel = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.nivel);
            estado = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.estado);
            colegio = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.colegio);
            especialidad = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.especialidad);
            codigo = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.codigo);
            this.listener = listener;
            v.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            listener.onItemClick(v, getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }

    public void setFilter(List<Plaza> items){
        //items = new ArrayList<>();
        //items.addAll(plazas);
        //notifyDataSetChanged();
        this.items=new ArrayList<>();
        this.items.addAll(items);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}


interface ItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(View view, int position);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que el problema que estás teniendo es que no rellenas la lista de plazas que tienes definida en tu Activity, por lo que al buscar sobre esa lista que está vacía no te da resultados, ya que cuando tu recibes los datos del WS los procesas y los metes directamente en tu adapter con:

```
 Plaza[] plazas = gson.fromJson(mensaje.toString(), Plaza[].class);
 // Inicializar adaptador
 adapter = new MetaAdapter(Arrays.asList(plazas), getActivity());
 // Setear adaptador a la lista
 lista.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Y al hacer la búsqueda estás pasandole la variable plazas que contiene una lista vacía:

```
ArrayList<Plaza> listaFiltrada =filter(plazas,newText);
adapter.setFilter(listaFiltrada);
```

Yo probaría a modificar el código de `procesarRespuesta` para que al recibir los datos los copie también en tu lista `plazas` quedando el cósigo de la siguiente forma:

```
 Plaza[] plazasResp = gson.fromJson(mensaje.toString(), Plaza[].class);
 plazas = Arrays.asList(plazasResp );
 // Inicializar adaptador
 adapter = new MetaAdapter(plazas, getActivity());
 // Setear adaptador a la lista
 lista.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Además de definir la variable `plazas` como private en tu Clase

```
private ArrayList<Plaza> plazas = new ArrayList<Plaza>();
```

Answer (score 1):

En vez de usar **MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener** utiliza el método del Searchview **setOnQueryTextListener**:

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            // Código al presionar buscar.
            actualizaPlazas(query);
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            // Código mientras cambia el texto.
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Tambien debes tener un método que actualice el ArrayList (en tu codigo, **plazas**) que usas en el adapter, algo así:

```
public ArrayList<Plaza> actualizaPlazas(String buscar){
    ArrayList<Plaza> plazasFiltrado = new ArrayList();
    //  Tu código.
    for (Plaza p : plazas){
        //  Condición para que filtre.
        if(p.plzNombre.equals(buscar)){
            plazasFiltrado.add(p);
        }
    }

   return plazasFiltrado;
}
```

Algo así es lo que podrías utilizar. Espero haber sido de ayuda. Saludos.

Comment: Soy novato en android :c como seria acomodado en mi codigo :c

Comment: Según lo que veo en tu código no tienes un método que filtre la palabra buscada y a la vez actualice el ArrayList que luego usas en el adaptador. Crea dicho método y luego lo llamas en el onQueryTextSubmit del setOnQueryTextListener, y te funcionará.

Comment: mucho para mi, porfa algun tutorial? para guiarme porfa :c

Comment: En el ejemplo cual seria su metodo de filtro?

Comment: Genera un método el cual reciba el ArrayList<Plaza> antes de pasarlo al método MetaAdapter, donde filtrarías con la palabra que estás usando en el SearchView. Qué vas a filtar, depende de tí, ya sea el nombre, id, número, etc. Armas el nuevo ArrayList<Plaza> y se lo envías al MetaAdapter. Modifiqué la respuesta, lo que te faltaría es llamar al adapter y refrescarlo. Saludos.

Comment: e modifcado el codigo pero ahroa no busca osea nisiquiera la lista blanca, me dices que lata algo mas?

Comment: estas refrescando el listView?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62882/discussion-between-ivan-more-flores-and-rostan).